# Highlight specific points from vector in scatterplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, highlight

I have a dataframe **df** with two columns, which are plotted in a scatterplot using ggplot. Now I have parted the curve into intervalls. The sectioning points of the intervalls are in a vector **r**. I now want to highlight these points to improve the visualization of the intervalls. I was thinking about coloring these intervall points or even to section the intervalls in adding vertical lines into the plot...I have tried some commands, but they didnt work for me. 
Here is an idea of how my data frame looks like:
**d** is first colume, **e** is the second with number of instances.

```
   d      e
   1      4
   2      4
   3      5
   4      5
   5      5
   6      4
   7      2
   8      3
   9      1
  10      3
  11      2
  12      3
  13      3
  14      3
  15      3
  16      3
  17      3
  18      4
```

My vector **r** shows, where the intervall borders were set.

```
7
8
9
10
11
12
18
```

Any ideas how to do so? Thanks!

Comment: Please post example of wanted output (you can upload a hand drawn picture).

Comment: Please also add what you tried (i.e. reproducible code) and why you're not happy with the outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try a `tidyverse`. The idea is to find overlapping points using ´mutate`and`%in%`, then color by the resutling logical vector`gr`. I also added vertical lines to illustrate the "intervals".

```
library(tidyverse)
d %>% 
  mutate(gr=d %in% r) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(d,e, color=gr)) + 
   geom_vline(xintercept=r, alpha=.1) +
   geom_point()
```

Edit: Without tidyverse you can add `gr` using

```
d$gr <- d$d %in% r
ggplot(d, aes(d,e, color=gr)) ...
```

[image]

The data

```
d <- read.table(text="  d      e
   1      4
                2      4
                3      5
                4      5
                5      5
                6      4
                7      2
                8      3
                9      1
                10      3
                11      2
                12      3
                13      3
                14      3
                15      3
                16      3
                17      3
                18      4", header=T)
r <- c(7:12,18)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have tried it, unfortunately R crashes everytime I am trying to load the package "tidyverse". So I just tried it with geom_vline and I get the vertical lines. When I try to plot ggplot with the color=gr, R says, it doesn't know what "gr" is...

Comment: @victoria14 please see my edits. You have to add `gr` to the data.frame `d`.

Comment: @ Jimbou, this gives me the error: Error in d$d : $ operator is invalid for atomic vector....